# how to set indent (with absolute units: px, inch... ) for multicell parapgraph of PyFPDF?

Tags: python-3.x, word-wrap, pyfpdf

How to set an indent for a paragraph with absolute units which is to be made pdf by PyFPDF lib?

When using textwrap as follows indent can't be set with absolute units and indent differs depending on the following paragraph

```
self.thetext = textwrap.indent(text=self.thetext, prefix='      ')
```

Comment: Please add some details. What is `textwrap`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html, in short, it's a module to arrange your string in a way you like